# How can I add Data Binding to dynamically added views in Android using JAVA?

Tags: java, android-databinding, dynamic-view

Here is the example of a view added programmatically:

```
final EditText edtText = new EditText(getAct());
        edtText.setLayoutParams(EncounterUtil.getParams());
        cellView.addView(edtText);
```

while cellView is a linear layout defined in XML file. And I want to add data binding to each view which is generated programmatically and added to parent LinearLayout "cellView"